# Getting connect UNKNOWN 127.0.0.1:27017 using MongoDB and MongoJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I am getting the below error while connecting to mongoDB using Node.js.

Error:

```
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
 Error: connect UNKNOWN 127.0.0.1:27017 - Local (undefined:undefined)
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at connect (net.js:843:14)
    at net.js:939:9
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

i am explaining my code below.

```
var mongo=require('mongojs');
var database='supplier';
var collections=['admin','supplier'];
var db=mongo("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/"+database, collections);
```

My mongoDB database is also running in the default port but still i can nor resolve this error.Please help me.

Comment: Maybe replace 127.0.0.1 with localhost ?

Comment: No,still the error is same.

Comment: Remove the port and it might work.

Comment: @shan1024 : I did as per you but still same error is there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the URL is not correct. You don't have to use `mongodb://`.

```
var mongo=require('mongojs');
var database='supplier';
var collections=['admin','supplier'];
var db=mongo("127.0.0.1:27017/"+database, collections);
```